# Unable to create proper rule for Firebase sub collections and roles

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am creating an ionic app with firebase integration, in which I create a post section in the app. Users can write posts like facebook and any authenticated user can comment on the posts,
Following is my database design of how I am storing the data :- posts/{postsDocument}/comments/{commentsDocument} 
Comments is sub-collection for postsDocument which holds all the comments for a particular post. Also postDocument and commentsDocument contains Firebase uid of the user.
I have written rule where any user can comment on post and read others comments but i want rules for where user can update his own comment and not others and also only post owner can delete a comment.
Check the rule below. Please help me with what I am missing

```
match /posts/{postId} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
  match /{comments}/{commentId} {
    allow read, create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    allow update: if ;
    allow delete: if ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following rule for your case

```
    match /posts/{postId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
      match /{comments}/{commentId} {
        allow read, create: if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow update: if resource.data.commentOwnderId == request.auth.uid;//commentOwnderId, firebase uid of the user who wrote the comment
        allow delete: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/posts/$(postId)).data.postOwnerId == request.auth.uid;//postOwnerId, firebase uid of the user who wrote the post
      }
    }
```